# Scraping info from large number of URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to scrape the info from powerplant in this website: https://www.marktstammdatenregister.de/MaStR/Einheit/Einheiten/OeffentlicheEinheitenuebersicht#stromerzeugung

For each ID, I need to access its own page and retrieve some specific information. As there are 4 tabs in a link (i.e. urls#tab1, urls#tab2...), 2 million IDs will create, making a total of 8 million links.

If I do a manual for-loop throguh each ID, my IPs could get locked.
Is there any other way to solve this specific issue?

Comment: You can use proxies, or you could add delays between your requests and hope they don't catch you

Comment: Any time estimate to scrape all of them?

Comment: On my machine it takes 1.02 seconds per url, so 8 * 1.02 * 1 000 000 = 8160000 seconds, so it will take around 90 days with one IP, assuming it runs 24/7, if you add delays it will be even worse. Assuming we add 5 sec delay, with one IP it will take 500 days with one ip and 5 days with 100 proxies if you run them in parallel.

Comment: You did note the export table bottom on the page?  I would recommend downloading the data to determine if you need to scrape this site at all.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

I translated it to english, and on the right, there's a button that allows to export a csv... Just download that file and parse it using any available CSV parser. I'll keep original answer because it does apply when there's no such option.

## Original answer

If they do not provide any API that gives easy access to the data, it most likely means that they do not really care or want others to get it.

They do not have robots.txt, so technically you a free to scrape their entire site and they have no right to complain.

Best way is to just... Try scraping it. More often than not, they have ratelimits, not actual bans, you could scrape as fast as possible then on failed requests, use exponential back-off - on first fail, wait 5 seconds before trying again, on second fail, 10 seconds before trying again, on third fail, 20 seconds... On first success, scrape at full speed again, and repeat it all once it fails again.

Or you can scrape slowly - full page all at once, then wait a minute, and so on.

If I was really worried about getting blocked indefinitely, I wouldn't worry too much about how long it will take, and scrape it slowly.

Websites more often than not run on dedicated servers and one scraper issuing even hundreds of requests per minute won't really make a dent in it's performance.

Comment: The csv file only contain some information, but we need to access to each ID and get further. Any ideas for using multiple proxies at a company's computer?

Comment: Depending on what you use to scrape, you setup the proxy by simply specifying it in connection settings of said library. Though, using public proxies is more likely to get you blocked than just using your home IP address, simply because proxies are abused for things like that.

Comment: Have you written any code to scrape the first page that you can share in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Sahsahae has emphasized on some good points like robots, using delays, etc. However, I would also like to emphasize on the usage of UserAgents and IPs.

Some websites/hosts have mechanisms to trace you if you are requesting the links from the same IP and UserAgents. In case you have a VPN, you can also switch between different IPs and break your scraping processes. However, for the UserAgent part, it is worth checking out [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/). The code block is really simple to integrate with the [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

In this way, you are not eliminating but at least reducing the possibility of the target host thinking it is the same person sending requests. A combination of delays, user agents and IP can help you if you really do not wish to get banned, or at least scrape as much as you can.